# jQuery hook on Facebook embed post finished

Tags: jquery, facebook, hook, jquery-events

Is there something I can bind a jQuery event to when is Facebook embed post is finished loading?

I need to trigger a masonry reload after all my Facebook posts are loaded, because they only have the right height after the content is loaded.

The closest I got was:

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
    $('iframe').on('load', function () {
        $container.masonry();
    });
});
```

But somehow the event is triggered sometimes before the content is loaded.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried? Having some code available will help us to help you.

Comment: Closest I got is included

Comment: Have a look at done() - https://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/

Answer (score 5):

If you invoke the XFBML parser directly (so use `xfbml=0` instead of the normally embedded `xfbml=1`) you can include a callback:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.XFBML.parse(null, function() {
        console.log("parsing is complete!");
    });
};
```

Comment: I'd like to stress the importance of adding `xfbml=0` to your embed. If you don't then the `fb-xfbml-state="rendered"` event may trigger before it actually finishes rendering. This should be marked the right answer.

Comment: Thanks! Where do i add ´xfbml=0´? In the code of the facebook-post or rather to the SDK-snippet?

Answer (score 3):

It occurred to me that there is another way, using the ready handler -

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
    $('iframe').ready(function () {
        $container.masonry();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This saved my bacon on a WordPress page using multiple oembed sources (Twitter, YouTube, Facebook).